How do I use a JOIN in Perl's DBIx::Class
Some time ago I worked my way trough a Node JS tutorial which leaned heavy on using an ORM to access the database. Allthough I did not like Node JS at all (it's just not for me) I did fancy the ORM concept.
Perl being my scripting lingo of choice I decided to dive into DBIx::Class, or DBIC. And I kinda got stuck when trying to access related data, using joins.
I'm working my way trough the MAN pages and am currently reading DBIx::Class::Manual::Joining
Created myself a sqlite database:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cd` (
        `id` integer primary key NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        `cd_title` TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        `year` Text Not Null
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `track` (
        `id` integer primary key NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        `cd_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
        `track_title` TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        FOREIGN KEY(`cd_id`) REFERENCES `cd`(`id`)
);

Insert Into cd (id, cd_title, year) Values
        (1, 'CD 1', '2004'),
        (2, 'CD 2', '1995'),
        (3, 'CD 3', '2014'),
        (4, 'CD 4', '2024')
;
Insert Into track (id,cd_id,track_title) Values
        (1,1,'Track 1 CD 1'),
        (2,1,'Track 2 CD 1'),
        (3,1,'Track 3 CD 1'),
        (4,1,'Track 4 CD 1'),
        (5,1,'Track 5 CD 1'),
        (6,2,'Track 1 CD 2'),
        (7,2,'Track 2 CD 2'),
        (8,2,'Track 3 CD 2'),
        (9,3,'Track 1 CD 3'),
        (10,3,'Track 2 CD 3'),
        (11,3,'Track 3 CD 3'),
        (12,3,'Track 4 CD 3'),
        (13,3,'Track 5 CD 3'),
        (14,4,'Track 2 CD 4'),
        (15,4,'Track 3 CD 4'),
        (16,4,'Track 4 CD 4'),
        (17,4,'Track 5 CD 4')
;


In essence 4 CDs each of them with a couple of tracks.
Schema files were made using dbicdump:
 dbicdump -o dump_directory=. Model::Schema dbi:SQLite:cds.sqlite

The schema files are kinda long, I'll spare you those. But since dbicdump made them I'm assuming them to be correct.
After that I wrote myself a little test script:
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use v5.20;
use Data::Dumper;
use DBIx::Class;
use lib '.';
use Model::Schema qw();
my $schema = Model::Schema->connect('dbi:SQLite:cds.sqlite');


my $cds = $schema->resultset('Cd')->search(
        {
                'cd_title' => { like => 'CD%'}
        },
        {

                join => 'tracks',
                order_by => ['tracks.id'],
        }
);

for my $cd ($cds->all()){
        say $cd->cd_title;
        say $cd->get_column('track_title');
}

Sort of like how the MAN page says.
But I can't get it to work!
CD 1
DBIx::Class::Row::get_column(): No such column 'track.track_title' on Model::Schema::Result::Cd at ./test.pl line 24

shell returned 2


It keeps complaining that it can't find the column 'track_title' in the 'track' table.
I allready tried all sort of variation of the column name. Like putting the table name in it like 'track.track_title', but reading the error message it seems to be doing that on its own anyway.
It does seem to get all the data. When I leave out the second 'say' line it does in fact print out the CD title for every track. The 'join' seems in fact to be working.
Checking the 'Track.pm' schema file I see the following columns being added:
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "id",
  { data_type => "integer", is_auto_increment => 1, is_nullable => 0 },
  "cd_id",
  { data_type => "integer", is_foreign_key => 1, is_nullable => 0 },
  "track_title",
  { data_type => "text", is_nullable => 0 },
);

One other thing I noticed:
The example in the MAN page uses a sort on 'tracks.id'. Where 'tracks' is the relation name, not the table name. Which is why I tried '$cd->get_column('tracks.track_title')' in the say, to no effect.
I really would like to take this hurdle.
Peter

You don't need joins to achieve this. You can use the relationships that dbicdump will have set up for you.
my $cd_rs = $schema->resultset('Cd');

for my $cd ($cd_rs->all) {
  say $cd->cd_title;
  for my $track ($cd->tracks) {
    say '* ', $track->track_title;
  }
}

Update: I forgot about The Joy of Prefetch!
Try this instead:
my $cd_rs = $schema->resultset('Cd');

for my $cd ($cd_rs->search({}, { prefetch => 'tracks' })->all) {
  say $cd->cd_title;
  for my $track ($cd->tracks) {
    say '* ', $track->track_title;
  }
}


While this works, it creates a lot of database queries. If you set the DBIC_TRACE=1 environment variable, you will see that it will fetch all CDs, and then do a SELECT query for each individual track.

@simbabque: Yep. Fixed now :-)

Figured it out (I think)
Seems that while doing the join you've allso have to select which columns to get from the relation:
my $cds = $schema->resultset('Cd')->search(
        {
                'cd_title' => { like => 'CD%'}
        },
        {

                join => 'tracks',
                '+select' => [ 'tracks.track_title'],
                '+as'   => ['tracktitle'],
        }
);

This gave me access to the column from the track table using:
for my $cd ($cds->all()){
        say $cd->cd_title;
        say $cd->get_column('tracktitle');
}

I thought the '+select' and '+as' were optional, turns out they are not.

It makes more sense to not bother with the +select stuff, but use prefetch instead of join. There's a very good explanation of how this works in https://stackoverflow.com/q/47861406/1331451.
